# Arcpy Calculate Field Formatting Syntax

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, geoprocessing, field-calculator, arcgis-10.2

I am trying to field calculate a double field (PID) to a new string field (PIN). Using:

```
qry = '"139-{}".format(!PID!)'
arcpy.CalculateField_management(out, "PIN", qry, "PYTHON")
```

Given a PID = 260360160 The output generated in string PIN field is:

PIN = 139-260360160.0

How can I get rid of the .0? I assume this is carry over from the original field being a double.

I am running ArcGIS 10.2 and Python 2.7.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the built-in `int()` function of python to convert what appears to be a float value in the `PID` field to an integer:

```
qry = '"139-{}".format(int(!PID!))'
```

This *should* return PIN = 139-260360160

You could also do this by specifying zero decimal places in your string formatting function:

```
qry = '"139-{:.0f}".format(!PID!)'
```

[Eight Bits Equals a Byte](http://ebeab.com/2012/10/10/python-string-format/) has a really useful page on string formatting in python.